# Discrete version of generalized beta distribution

Tags: probability

I am not a mathematical guy. I need a quick help:

How do I analytically derive probability density function of $y$  with the following relationship (discrete version of generalized beta distribution)?

$y= f(r) = A(N+1-r)^a/r^b$

Note: this is taken from http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObject.action?uri=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0004791&representation=PDF

Comment: For discrete distribution density is just probability at point: $f(x) = P(\zeta = x)$. The function written above should be it.

Comment: However, formally discrete random variable doesn't have density, because it is not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure (discrete variable uses counting measure). It is called probability mass function.

Comment: You just write sums instead of integrals.

Comment: But it is going  to be inconvenient for me in that way. I rather need a close approximation of continuous distribution of $y$ or at least the inverted version of the expression i.e., $r = f'(y)$

Comment: Check these links, here people fit data with DGBD: [http://chengjun.github.io/en/2014/03/fit-power-law/](http://chengjun.github.io/en/2014/03/fit-power-law/)     [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446006/why-is-curve-so-different-from-lines-and-points-in-r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446006/why-is-curve-so-different-from-lines-and-points-in-r)